# Change time between screensaver-start and screen-lock

Tags: windows, windows-10, screensaver, lock-screen

When the screensaver starts there are a couple of seconds I can tap any key and stop the screensaver ***without*** the screen becoming locked, despite having the `on resume, display logon screen`-checkbox checked in Screen Saver Settings. Only after around 3 seconds does the computer become locked.

Is there a way to change that time (-the time between screensaver-start and screen-lock)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be configured through the Registry (and the default value is **5** seconds):

- Key: `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon`
- Value: `ScreenSaverGracePeriod`
- Type: REG_DWORD
- Value: time in seconds

(Source: various google results for "windows screensaver grace period")

Comment: Thanks. I tried searching with other keywords. But "Grace Period" is the key.

Answer (score 0):

I think so, look in the local security policies
start menu > run > secpol.msc

local policies>security options>interactive session openings
sorry but my w10 is in french i hope this will put you on the right track.

nice day